# call method from other application

Tags: vb.net, methods, vb6, call

I have application 'a' (vb6) and application 'b' (vb.net). What is the best way to call method in 'a' using 'b' source code? I mean 'a' is recording calling numbers and when particular number calls it should change application's 'b' panel text (name). 
Yes, app 'a' could save all calling numbers to text file and 'b' could check for that particular number every one second or so, but it would be not efficient at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Make a into an ActiveX EXE and raise an event.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of both applications?  And they can be freely modified?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use Sockets. Put one socket in Project A and another in Project B and allow them to talk to each other. This way an event is raised everytime data is sent from Socket to the other